# How to locate blocks on disks that are used by pagefile.sys?

Tags: windows, pagefile

Using powershell, I am able to locate the pagefiles. This is good so far.

But I'm having trouble in determining which blocks on the filesystem are consumed by the pagefile.sys file.

Is there any way for me to know that data? I'm trying to get the list of blocks for the pagefile so that I can potentially eliminate writing those blocks when I do a block level backup of a vmware vm.

I thought that fsutil.exe would be able to provide it but that's not the case. Is there a built in binary that will show me the list of blocks for a particular file?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the file before you perform the backup?

Comment: @Ramhound because i'm not backing up the filesystems by traversing it. I'm requesting a list of changed blocks from vmware. At the block level, there's no indications of what is the pagefile and what isn't. Thanks for commenting.